# How can i define my own Theme Resource Keys inside my class library and override them on the App?

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I would like to define custom ThemeResource keys inside my class library and use it in UserControls also defined inside my
class library.
I then have a need for my Application to override those values.

Here's a concrete example.

I need to define an AppColor ThemeResource key inside my class library. UserControls inside the class library should be able to reference and use it.
Now each individual Application that uses my library should be able to redefine this key and specify it's own specific Application color.

How do i structure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this would work, but my first guess would be to add resources to your `generic.xaml` in the class library. I'm assuming this class library has your shared controls and they'll have their base styles initialized in `generic.xaml`.

In `generic.xaml`, add themed resources like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyAppColor" Color="Orange" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaryies>

<Style TargetType="Controls:MyControl">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource MyAppColor}"/>
</Style>
```

Any app that references your DLL would be able to modify the MyAppColor resource in their dictionaries the same way. For example, you can add this to `App.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyAppColor" Color="Green" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaryies>
```

If you don't know what `generic.xaml` is, a simple Google search will yield a lot of help. It's basically a reserved resource dictionary file-name that will allow you to define your styles implicitly.

Comment: VERY good sir! I was creating a separate ThemeResources.xaml (similar to what i was seeing inside MS folders) but wasnt working.

Comment: I can't get this to work, the control always keeps the color defined in the class library, no matter which value I define in the App.xaml

Comment: Dominik, maybe post a code sample so we can help you out. Create another post and share the link in a comment here.